# deleting single row parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to delete a single row from Parse but i don't know how to do that. I have a tableView with some names on it taken from Parse, when i use commitEditingStyle function i would like to delete the name from Parse.
I wrote this code but its not complete, i don't know how to finish it:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        var friendSelected:String = friendsArray[indexPath.row]
        friendsArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        // Remove From Parse

        var tempArrayFriend:[String] = [String]()

        var query = PFQuery(className:"Friend")
        query.whereKey("UserKey", containsString: PFUser.currentUser()?.username)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            for friend in objects! {
                let friendFromParse:String? = (friend as! PFObject)["Friend"] as? String
                // Aggiungo i voti all'array corrispondete
                if friendFromParse != nil {

                    tempArrayFriend.append(friendFromParse!)

                    friend.removeObjectForKey(friendSelected)

            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
            }       
        }    
    }
```

I would like to delete a single row from Parse where the key is PFUser.username! Thank you and i hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Try this:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
    var friendSelected:String = friendsArray[indexPath.row]
    friendsArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    // Remove From Parse


    var query = PFQuery(className:"Friend")
    query.whereKey("UserKey", containsString: PFUser.currentUser()?.username)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
        for friend in objects! {
            friend.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
        } 
      } else {
            // Log details of the failure
        }       
    }    
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want to delete the objects, from what I understood, he wants to remove a property on the object

Comment: Well maybe he can provide some clarification. His last line says "I would like to delete a single row from Parse..."

Comment: Yes i would like to delete a sigle row from Parse but pbush your method doesnt do nothing! The line still remain!

Comment: I'm a little confused by your logic. You're removing a row from your table view data source by using the value at the index path, but you're trying to remove a row from Parse seemingly based on a different property, so I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. The method works, so my guess is that it's not returning anything. Before `friend.deleteInBackground`, put `println(friend)` and make sure it's the right `Friend` object that you're trying to delete.

Comment: yes the object is right, but I have this error now: 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'deleteInBackground()' at the line: friend.deleteInBackground()

Comment: What did you change? It wasn't giving you that before so you had to have made some modification. To fix the new error try `for friend in objects! as PFObject { }`

Comment: i did't change anything! do you try this code on your xcode? now after adding "as PFObject" there is one ore error: Type 'PFObject' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

Comment: No sorry I'm not on my Mac but I have a lot of experience with Parse so I'm trying to help you out. What if you try the deleteInBackgroundWithBlock method, and force friend as! PFObject

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry it was complicated, happy coding!